# how to get the currently running thread in ExecutorService

Tags: multithreading, executorservice, java-6

I got a pool of threads using ExecutorService, this executorService will execute the runnable class I implemented, and now I'd like to get the currently running thread in this pool, how? Please help, thanks.

```
Thread currThread  = Thread.currentThread();
```

Will this get the current running thread in the pool?

Comment: you mean how to execute them ?

Comment: @user2720864 no, I just want to get the current thread that is running....

Comment: can you share some code and show us what exactly the issue ?

Comment: `Thread currThread  = Thread.currentThread();` will return a reference to the currently executing thread object. where are you calling this .. share your code please, your question is not very clear

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread currThread  = Thread.currentThread()
```

write the above code in your part of code which is shared between pool of threads.